A validation error occurs when using CSS nesting
When written as described in the CSS Nesting Module,
The W3C CSS Validation Service displays an Parse Error. What is the reason?
.foo {
  color: red;

  .bar {
    color: blue;
  }
}

Is there any way to eliminate the error?

forget about the validator, it's never up to date and will give you error even for very old features

Suggest you look for an alternative validation solution. Stylelint is one possibility.

The status of the document is the key here. The CSS Nesting Module is still in draft status.
You have three choices:

Wait until the spec becomes a recommendation (probably several years). I assume that once this happens, the W3C will update their validator.
Ignore the validation error message, or don’t use the W3C validator.
Avoid nesting.


https://caniuse.com/css-nesting
